# Is possible to insert a new item in the middle of a hash and have it reindex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, insert

I have this as a hash :

```
>> params[:payments]

{"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
{"1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
{"2"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
```

Is it possible to make a new hash and insert it into a specific place ? For example, take this line :

```
{"2"=>{":amount_paid"=>"1.00", ":date_paid"=>"1/1/2006"}}
```

So that the hash will appear as this now :

```
{"0"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
{"1"=>{":amount_paid"=>"1.00", ":date_paid"=>"1/1/2006"}}  # <-- Newly inserted line
{"2"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
{"3"=>{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}}
```

Comment: Is a Hash really the correct data structure for your use case?

Comment: are you implying that there is no reasonable solution to this?

Comment: The problem is that Hashes aren't ordered, as answered below. The order is arbitrary. You could do it, probably, by creating a new hash when you add the new hash item.

Comment: @philosodad hashes are now ordered in Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @phoffer While hashes maintain their order of insertion in 1.9.2, you can't modify this order (without doing something painful like removing all of the values after the index you want to insert at, and reinserting them after your new value). This is a super useful new feature of 1.9.2 in many other cases though!

Comment: @ddagradi right that you can't modify it. But it is super nice that they are just ordered at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using an Array, as hashes are not inherently ordered. Ruby's Array.insert lets you specify where to insert your new objects (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000230), and using your example above, we get:

```
arr = [{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"},
{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"},
{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}]

arr.insert(2, {"some hash"}) 

[{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"},
{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"},
{"some hash"},
{":amount_paid"=>"100.00", ":date_paid"=>"2/20/2009"}]
```

You can then iterate over the indices and maintain your desired order while adding to it.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.9+, Hashes are not ordered, instead, they maintain the order that entries are inserted:

From the docs:

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

```
require 'pp'

hash = {
  'a' => 1,
  'c' => 3
}

hash['b'] = 2

pp hash
# >> {"a"=>1, "c"=>3, "b"=>2}
```

As an alternate to sorting the hash keys then iterating over the hash, the hash itself can be sorted, then regenerated if you want to walk it directly:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :010 > Hash[*hash.sort.flatten]
 => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}
```

Use it like:

```
hash = Hash[*hash.sort.flatten]
```

It's probably faster with a big hash to sort the keys then walk them, but if you gotta have the hash in order that will do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you had to do this with a Hash, and you didn't want to use the index of an array, you would create a new class, OrderedHash. In that class, you need to create an `insert` and `delete` method that enforces the following properties:

Insert:

1. a new entry has a key that is in
   range (<= the largest current key).
2. If a new entry has a key that is
   already used, for each number from
   the current new key value to the
   largest value, increment the key
   value by one. Probably best to do
   this from the largest down to the
   smallest to avoid problems.
3. Insert new Entry

Delete: When an entry is deleted, decrement the key value for all keys > the deletion value.

Comment: FYI, there's an [OrderedHash](http://rdoc.info/gems/orderedhash/0.0.6/frames) gem available if you don't want to reinvent that wheel.